# Check if a css button is selected or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Have to check if a css button is selected, or not.

If it is on then :

`uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18">`

If it is off then :

`uib-tooltip="The Customer is over 18">`

Too decide if my script has to click on it or not. How do i check this ?.

This is the xpath i am using to currently click it / off on :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie')]"));
```

But need a check before it, whether i need to click or not.

```
<age-question-button class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" state="qc.answer[question.name]" icon="plus-18-movie" active-text="The Customer is over 18" inactive-text="The Customer is NOT over 18" ng-repeat="question in qc.questionsList track by question.name" audit="cc.utils.audit(qc.answer[question.name] ? question.auditInactive : question.auditActive)">
<label class="c-option u-p-0 u-ml-md u-pull-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="The Customer is over 18">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="state" ng-change="audit()" style="" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie"></i>
</label>

<label class="c-option u-p-0 u-ml-md u-pull-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="state" ng-change="audit()" style="" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie"></i>
```

[Clickable Image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpOR9.png)

Comment: Can you clarify if it is a `button` or a `checkbox`? If it is a `Button` it can't be selected but can be clicked. As a `checkbox` it can be selected. Also consider updating at which state `ON` or `OFF` you want to click & which option you want to click.

Comment: it is a button.

Comment: But the html you provided seems that it is checkbox.. ???

Comment: `type="checkbox"`

Comment: yes i have seen ..?
I have attached a screenshot of the button to help clarify.
Button in question is currently selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can check like below

```
 WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie')]"));

 boolean isChecked = element.findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();
 if(isChecked){
    element.click();
 }
```

Comment: If you want to do nothing if it is selected then try with reverse logic. Use it appropriately with your need

Comment: It fails on the Boolean check :-  
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"input"}  It doesn't behave as as a normal button,  I think i need a method to get out "uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18" ....